Pandas Flatten Row When Doing Groupby
I have a Pandas dataframe that has address and contact information. The rows are on occasion duplicated because there are different values in the respective contact information (the address information remains the same for each vendor ID)
ID    Vendor Name     Vendor Address       City    State     Zip      Email     Phone    Name
 1         Google      123 Street St    Example       CA   94000                         John
 1         Google      123 Street St    Example       CA   94000    a@b.com
 2      Microsoft      456 County Rd     Madeup       NY   12345    c@d.com                    
 2      Microsoft      456 County Rd     Madeup       NY   12345              555-1234  
 2      Microsoft      456 County Rd     Madeup       NY   12345                         Jane

How do I group by the ID field and flatten the Email, Phone, and Name fields (assume there are no collisions where there is a value )
For the example provided, the result would be:
ID    Vendor Name     Vendor Address       City    State     Zip      Email     Phone    Name
 1         Google      123 Street St    Example       CA   94000    a@b.com              John
 2      Microsoft      456 County Rd     Madeup       NY   12345    c@d.com   555-1234   Jane      

I saw from this answer that I can do something like:
 df.groupby(by='ID').apply(lambda group: ','.join(group['Email']))

but this would only join one column.

Make sure your blanks  are np.nan values:
df.groupby(['ID','Vendor Name', 'Vendor Address', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'], as_index=False).first()

Output:
   ID Vendor Name Vendor Address     City State    Zip    Email     Phone  Name
0   1      Google  123 Street St  Example    CA  94000  a@b.com      None  John
1   2   Microsoft  456 County Rd   Madeup    NY  12345  c@d.com  555-1234  Jane

With df,
data = {'ID': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Vendor Name': {0: 'Google',
  1: 'Google',
  2: 'Microsoft',
  3: 'Microsoft',
  4: 'Microsoft'},
 'Vendor Address': {0: '123 Street St',
  1: '123 Street St',
  2: '456 County Rd',
  3: '456 County Rd',
  4: '456 County Rd'},
 'City': {0: 'Example', 1: 'Example', 2: 'Madeup', 3: 'Madeup', 4: 'Madeup'},
 'State': {0: 'CA', 1: 'CA', 2: 'NY', 3: 'NY', 4: 'NY'},
 'Zip': {0: 94000, 1: 94000, 2: 12345, 3: 12345, 4: 12345},
 'Email': {0: np.nan, 1: 'a@b.com', 2: 'c@d.com', 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan},
 'Phone': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: '555-1234', 4: np.nan},
 'Name': {0: 'John', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: 'Jane'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


@bijan Did this solution help you?  Consider accepting thanks.
